# TypeError: nodeIdListOfPrevValue.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, foreach, axios

I am using an axios get request to fetch some data.
I am iterating through that data using forEach because i need to set up the variable names for id and label since i am using vue treeSelect. 
In the moment i try to use the component i receive the "TypeError: nodeIdListOfPrevValue.forEach is not a function".

What's wrong with my forEach here?

```
.then(response =>
        response.data.forEach((element, index) => {
           const data = {
            id: index,
            label: element.purpose
          }

          me.purposeList.push(data);

          console.log(data.id)
          console.log(data.label)      
        })
```

The data i am fetching is an array of objects

Response.data: [image]

that looks something like this:

```
[
  0: {purposeId: 1, purpose: "aaaa"}
  1: {purposeId: 2, purpose: "bbbb"}
  2: {purposeId: 3, purpose: "cccc"}
]
```

Axios call:

```
var me = this;
axios
.get(this.$baseURL + '/api/GetPurposeList',
{
  headers: {Authorization: this.loggedUser.token},
  params: {
  email: this.email,
  sourceId: this.sourceId,
  purposeId: this.purposeId
  },
})
```

The vue tree-select is being used like this:

```
<treeselect 
  v-model="purpose" 
  :multiple="true" 
  :options="purposeList"
  placeholder="Purpose"/>
```

And the variable "purpose" is defined on data(){ ... } as "purpose":null

The variable after i select an element from tree-select:

[image]

Then i assign it to:

```
this.purpose = this.purpose[0].toString()
```

If i display in on console i get the expected "2"

Comment: Foreach is not faulty. Are you sure it is an array of response.data?

Comment: inside .then i think it will look better if after "=>" you wrapped it in { ... } cause forEach returns nothing; also do console.log(Array.isArray(response.data)), and make sure "me" variable is defined; if none of this helped maybe it is better to add the axios call as well, so we can see what is before "then"

Comment: @MahirAltınkaya yeah quite sure, just updated a print of the response.data in the console

Comment: @mdln97 updated with { } after '=>' and the isArray() method returned true.
The "me" variable is just "var me = this". Yeah i know it is stupid, but i didn't make this code, just making a few changes on it.
I will show update the post with the axios call

Comment: i think your problem might be lying somewhere else, do you have anywhere in your code something like "nodeIdListOfPrevValue" ? it might be a name of a variable

Comment: I tried your code. its working. you have to change only then(response=>{
 response.data.forEach((element, index) => {
           const data = {
            id: index,
            label: element.purpose
          }

          me.purposeList.push(data);

          console.log(data.id)
          console.log(data.label)      
        })
})

Comment: @mdln97 no, it is a really weird error, i think the problem lays on the vue tree-select because the error is only displayed when i try to execute a function with data from it

Comment: @MahirAltınkaya that code seems equal to i what i have.
Think you are talking about response { .... }.
I already updated

Comment: This is @riophae/vue-treeselect and not vue-treeselect, isn't it? The question doesn't even mention this. Yes, the problem is related to it. It's impossible to solve your problem without debugging it. Please, provide a way to replicate it.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes it is. How do i provide that?

Comment: Try to provide a minimal demo that allows to debug the problem with something like Codesandbox that has Vue support, also post relevant code in the question, currently there are only separate snippets. This will help.

Comment: @EstusFlask codesandbox link in the post

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the error, see https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lalande-e6sdy . You can replace `axios.get(...)` with hard-coded `Promise.resolve({ data: [...] })` to simplify it.

Comment: @EstusFlask i changed this.purpose = this.purpose[0].toString() to this.purpose = this.purpose.join() and no more errors